# CSS reset causes tables not to look right

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-tables

I applied the following CSS reset to my website's CSS stylesheet (validating as CSS 2.0 and used with XHTML 1.0 transitional webpage)

`html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;}`

However, in my website I have a table that no longer looks right. More precisely, the table is now out of position and the borders (originally black) are no longer visible.

I'm wondering if I should just zap off the table, border rules ar if I can keep the reset as is and tell the browser later on to display or not the borders. My main hesitation is that I'd like to keep the same reset for all my pages and that changing the reset just for the pages that have tables (tabular data) will only make everything complicated, since I'm using a EXTERNAL STYLESHEET.

Comment: Why are you surprised that setting border to 0 in your CSS for tables removes table borders? A reset is not designed to look good, it is designed to level the playing field across browsers.

Comment: A live link would be very helpful - any chance of that? (@RedFilter makes a good point though :)

Comment: Where in your css is this reset at? At the top? If it's after the styles for your table, then this will take precedence.

Comment: ok for the reset notion, it insures that website looks the same on all web browsers.

Comment: yes dozer blake my reset is at the very top of the css stylesheet

Comment: Need a reset for your reset! (Or maybe just don't try substituting heavy libraries you haven't read for learning what you're dealing with.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick fix: just remove all table code from your reset

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{

margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
font-size:100%;
font:inherit;
vertical-align:baseline;}
```

Better fix, use a **css normalizer** rather than a **reset**: take a look at the one used by the [html5boilerplate project](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

Comment: that may be the solution, will it affect the rest of my reset ?

Comment: no, I just removed `table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,` from it, so your other styles are unaffected

Comment: Better yet, learn the incredibly few defaults and fashion your own base starter CSS as desired. There is no substitute for knowing what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something (I don't know what you mean by "css reset"), you are telling it that table, td, th (and a load of other tags) are to display no borders. So why do you expect your table to have borders after that?

Comment: I'm assuming they have the table styled as well, but it sounds like this is loading after that style and maybe they don't understand CSS is going to go from top to bottom and apply them.

Answer (score 1):

After troubleshooting a similar issue I found that the reset css had the table property of:

border-collapse:collapse; which was causing the border not be displayed.

Adding...
border-collapse:separate; to my applied css fixed the problem.